# Nearest neighbor zones visualized

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, data-visualization, kdtree, space-partitioning

I'm writing an app that looks up points in two-dimensional space using a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdtree). It would be nice, during development, to be able to "see" the nearest-neighbor zones surrounding each point.

In the attached image, the red points are points in the k-d tree, and the blue lines surrounding each point bound the zone where a nearest neighbor search will return the contained point.

The image was created thusly:

```
for each point in the space:
  da = distance to nearest neighbor
  db = distance to second-nearest neighbor
  if absolute_value(da - db) < 4:
    draw blue pixel
```

This algorithm has two problems:

- (more important) It's slow on my (reasonably fast Core i7) computer.
- (less important) It's sloppy, as you can see by the varying widths of the blue lines.

What is this "visualization" of a set of points called?

What are some good algorithms to create such a visualization?

[image: partitions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a **[Voronoi Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)** and there are many excellent algorithms for generating them efficiently.  The one I've heard about most is **[Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm)**, which runs in time O(n log n), though others algorithms exist for this problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Jacob,

hey, you found an interesting way of generating this Voronoi diagram, even though it is not so efficient.

The less important issue first: the varying thickness boundaries that you get, those butterfly shapes, are in fact the area between the two branches of an hyperbola. Precisely the hyperbola given by the equation |da - db| = 4. To get a thick line instead, you have to modify this criterion and replace it by the distance to the bisector of the two nearest neighbors, let A and B; using vector calculus, | PA.AB/||AB|| - ||AB||/2 | < 4.

The more important issue: there are two well known efficient solutions to the construction of the Voronoi diagram of a set of points: Fortune's sweep algorithm (as mentioned by templatetypedef) and Preparata & Shamos' Divide & Conquer solutions. Both run in optimal time O(N.Lg(N)) for N points, but aren't so easy to implement.

These algorithm will construct the Voronoi diagram as a set of line segments and half-lines. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram.

This paper "Primitives for the manipulation of general subdivisions and the computation of Voronoi" describes both algorithms using a somewhat high-level framework, caring about all implementation details; the article is difficult but the algorithms are implementable.

You may also have a look at "A straightforward iterative algorithm for the planar Voronoi diagram", which I never tried.

A totally different approach is to directly build the distance map from the given points for example by means of Dijkstra's algorithm: starting from the given points, you grow the boundary of the area within a given distance from every point and you stop growing when two boundaries meet. [More explanations required.] See http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-O6rXggLa9fE/TnAwz4f9hXI/AAAAAAAAAPk/0vrqEKRPVIw/s1600/distmap-20-seed4-fin.jpg

Another good starting point (for efficiently computing the distance map) can be "A general algorithm for computing distance transforms in linear time".

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience: Fortune's algorithm is a pain to implement. The divide and conquer algorithm presented by Guibas and Stolfi isn't too bad; they give detailed pseudocode that's easy to transcribe into a procedural programming language. Both *will* blow up if you have nearly degenerate inputs and use floating point, but since the primitives are quadratic, if you can represent coordinates as 32-bit integers, then you can use 64 bits to carry out the determinant computations.

Once you get it working, you might consider replacing your kd-tree algorithms, which have a Theta(√n) worst case, with algorithms that work on planar subdivisions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a great implementation for it at D3.js library: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/voronoi.html

Comment: thanks for the link. I ended up using the D3 implementation and it's been great.